# What do relay switching characteristics mean?

Tags: relay, switching

I am looking for HV realys (3kV) and found a supplier for that. Now they offer relays with different switching characteristics:
"No Load"
"Make & Break"
"Make only"
"Carry only"

On the web page there is no explanation for that. Can you give me a hint of the meaning of these characteristica?

Comment: I would write an answer but I'm not confident enough to, especially around "carry-only". I can tell you that what it's referring to is the relay's ability to switch reliably and safely while there's current flowing; no load, for instance, would mean the relay cannot be turned on or off while there's a load connected (it would arc, damaging the contacts).

Comment: A link to the web-page is required of course.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the datasheet will make this less ambiguous, but these normally relate to the current carrying and breaking capability.

Your relay may withstand a 3 kV potential when open, or making a circuit - and a 3A current once the circuit is closed. What it may not withstand is more than 0.5A to make or break the circuit (as the contacts become close enough for breakdown, or as an arc is drawn and extinguished).

If the make/break capacity is not high enough, you will only be able to use these components with a secondary current limiting feature.